# How do I return multiple rows from multiple specific index ranges?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 50 rows and I'm trying to get the data in rows 5-10, 12 and 21-23. Is there any way to do this in a single line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just concatenate into a `vector` and use it as row index  - for those sequence in range, use `:`

```
df1[c(5:10, 12, 21:23),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in base R you could use `rbind`:

```
rbind(df[5:10,], df[12,], df[21:23,])
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)

index_range <- c(5:10, 12, 21:23)

df %>% 
  slice(index_range)
```